# ¿Dónde asigno el Channel y ClientId en la SDK de Google Maps para iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3

Tengo un código Swift. Quiero obtener reportes de trafico por los canales utilizados con Google Maps SDK para iOS.

La documentación de Google Maps SDK dice que se debe incluir el **clientId** y **channel** en la solicitud. ¿Pero dónde exactamente pongo el clientId y el channel en mi petición? 
A continuación, mi código:

```swift
import UIKit

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let googleMapsApiKey = "MY_GOOGLE_IOS_API_KEY"

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleMapsApiKey)
        return true
    }
}
```

¿Alguien puede ayudar?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Equivalent in Javascript is: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&channel=YOUR_CHANNEL"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente es el código que tú has puesto. Tienes que obtener una clave de Google con el [paso 4 del tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start?hl=es-419#paso_4_obtener_una_clave_de_api) y una vez la tengas sólo tienes que escribirla en `GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")` en el `AppDelegate.swift`

Lo que si recomiendo es no ponder la API_KEY en texto plano en el archivo `AppDelegate.swift`. Puedes pasarla al archivo `info.plist` y obtenerla con [este](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24604793/4229896) procedimiento.